# Is it possible to use array_shift() in PHP and get the key?

Tags: php, sorting, arrays

I have a list of files in an array where the filename is the key and the value is the last modified date in seconds. They are sorted from oldest to newest.

The files are `glob()`'d in, and then sorted this way using

```
asort($fileNameToLastModified, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

I use [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to get the oldest file. Unfortunately, it seems to be giving me the value, and there doesn't seem to be a way to get the key.

Would the only way to do that be something like this?

```
$keys = array_keys($fileNameToLastModified);

$oldest = array_shift($keys);
array_shift($fileNameToLastModified); // to manually chop the first array member off too.
```

...or is there a built-in method to do it?

Comment: for those who just want the key of first item (after sorting), `array_keys($my_arr)[0]` would work (though it'll be expensive for long arrays)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$result = array_splice( $yourArray, 0, 1 );
```

... should do the trick. See [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

Comment: I ended up just keeping what I had, because with this I still need to do an `array_keys()` and get an array member. But this is still another way to do it, so I'll accept it :)

Comment: I think you mean `$result = key(array_splice( $yourArray, 0, 1 ));` ?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `each` like:

```
$b = array(1=>2, 3=>4, 7=>3);
while(1) {
    list($key,$value) = each($b);
    if (empty($key))
        break;
    echo "$key $val\n";
}
```

Iterating the array with `each` will keep its last position.

Answer (score 3):

Different approach:

```
list ($key, $value) = each($srcData); array_shift($srcData);
```

... (or just `list($key)...` if you doesn't need `$value`). See [each](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) and [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

**Edit:** As @ztate pointed in his comment, `each()` function have been deprecated so relying in this approach is no longer a good idea.

But I think similar behaviour can be approached by using the new `key()` function this (untested) way:

```
$key = key($srcData); $selected = array_shift($srcData);
```

Comment: Warning: `Each` function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Comment: Whole PHP is deprecated for me. But good point: it seems it is a new victim of the usual PHP inconsistence across versions so this approach shoud not be used (even I don't trust it would save you from other changes). BTW I figure out similar behavior could be approached by new functions `key()`, `current()` and `next()`. Three function calls instead of one (despite the `list()` call that certainly could be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
<?php

$arr = array('a' => 'first', 'b' => 'second');

// This is your key,value shift line
foreach($arr as $k => $v) { break; }

echo "Key: $k\nValue: $k";
```

This will output:

```
Key: a
Value: first
```

I'm not sure how the performance is, so you might want to do some profiling, but it's likely to be faster than `array_keys()` for large arrays, since it doesn't need to iterate over the whole thing.

Comment: Since it copies the whole `$arr`, I'd say it could be terrible on big arrays.

Comment: `foreach()` shouldn't copy the array, surely?

Comment: It doesn't copy the array if all the body has is `break`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at `key()`, `current()` or `each()`. They do what you asked for.

I'm not really sure if you intend to actually get more key/value pairs from the array afterwards. So I won't get into any details of what else you might need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility which is short working:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) break;
unset($array[$key]);
```